# Drunk man on a cliff

Tags: probability, puzzle, random-walk

This question is an extension of the already fairly well discussed problem [Does the drunk man fall off the cliff?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/does-the-drunk-man-fall-off-the-cliff-a-random-walk-problem)

A few people raised this question of why the probability should not be 1, i.e. why does the drunk man not always fall off given he has infinite steps to take.

As quoted by a user in [his answer.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6439)

> If allowed to randomly step indefinitely means he keeps stepping
>   until he falls off the cliff.

Some arguments against this were:

1. "There are many infinite sequences of steps which never cross the cliff."
2. "So If you could somehow collect an infinitely large set of computers and run a simulation, I maintain that a nonzero fraction of them would run without halting forever!"

*To this I would ask: what about the case when q < 1 / 2. In that case the agreed upon answer is 1. So aren't there still infinite sequences of steps which never cross the cliff?*

Comment: @DanielSank you seem to have clarity on this. Could you explain?

Comment: There are lots of possible sequences which never cross the cliff, but the cumulative probability of all the sequences is zero. The possible sequences of steps are the same whatever the probability of left and right - the probabilities govern which sequences are most likely to be taken.

Comment: So if there are 8 such sequences, but infinitely many, where he does fall - you can't claim the probability is non-zero.

Comment: When $p$ and $q$ are not equal (i.e. not both $\frac12$), different sequences have different likelihoods

Comment: 2. If you had uncountably many computers (one for each possible path), then infinitely many of them would run without halting forever, but the "size" (measure) of this infinite set of non-halting computers with respect to the total amount of computers will be zero, like the measure of $\mathbb{N}$ inside $\mathbb{R}$. (Here we would be in the case $p=1/2$, because each path corresponds to a computer which is like all the others).

Comment: @MarkBennet "the probabilities govern which sequences are most likely to be taken" - Agreed. But the cumulative probability can't be zero right? It maybe a number arbitrarily close to zero. And hence the probability of falling in that case arbitrarily close to one.

Comment: @57Jimmy Nice way to look at it but how can you so comfortably say that the "size" of the set of non-halting computers is almost 0 compared to total number of computers? Knowing the answer, one could arrive at this argument to explain it, but what about the other way around?

Comment: @user3286661 Within the closed interval of real numbers $[0,1]$ the rational numbers have measure zero - there are infinitely many of them. It is possible to have an infinite subset of possibilities yet the probability of choosing one is zero.

Comment: I think all confusion lies in the way of perceiving different infinities. What I can't seem to digest is the fact that the ratio of sizes of two different infinities can be zero. In other words, the confusion I think lies in exactness vs limiting behavior. Probability being exactly 1 is what is making me uncomfortable.

Comment: When dealing with infinite amounts of possible outcomes, there is a difference between "Something will happen in all cases" and "Something will happen with probability 1". If it happens in all cases, then it will happen with probability 1, but not the other way around. If one is coming from the combinatorics side and considers probabilities as essentially $\frac{\rm{good cases}}{\rm{all cases}}$, then the difference may be hard to understand.

Comment: @user3286661 Yes, this is exactly the main problem. It has to do with measure theory. We are not talking of measure almost $1$ or almost $0$, it is actually $1$ (or $0$). Which, as Ingix points out, does not imply that it includes all cases (or none). A probability is a measure that has maximal value $1$ (roughly speaking). There are good reasons why one has to look at things like this and there are also good and satisfying answers, although more complicated than in the finite cases. A related point is that with infinities you cannot just sum outcomes, you need to integrate a measure.

Comment: @user3286661 If you take a square with area one, say $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and delete a finite number of points, what area do you get? Still $1$: the single points have no area. Not something close to $1$, but really $1$. And the same is true if you delete a countable amount of points, even all points with rational coordinates (although this is not trivial to see). This is exactly the same as with probabilities, just a bit more familiar. An area and a probability are both measures.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are still infinitely many sequences never crossing the cliff, but they make up a set of measure zero in the set of all sequences.

Comment: What about this argument when q > 1/2. in this case the motion will have a clear drift eastward and after many steps we will see a normal distribution with a peak at some point to the right of 0 and when time increases indefinitely the proportion of men to the left of 0 will tend to 0 and hence the probability of dying tends to 0?

Comment: No: In the above thought experiment there is just a red line, hence nobody will fall off the cliff. In the real experiment the fraction $p$ of the men will fall off the cliff on their first step.